# Delegate creating new instance of ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am sending a data to a view controller through a delegate method.  In the view controller that receives the data if I `print(self)` in `viewDidLoad` I get this value:

```
<PageViewControllerImage: 0x7fba16d0dc40>
```

and if I `print(self)` in the delegate function I get this value:

```
<PageViewControllerImage: 0x7fba16e0eab0>
```

I believe the is how I define the delegate, it is creating a new instance of the `PageViewControllerImage`, but I can't figure out how to get the existing reference to it?

This is what I'm using to set the delegate inside the class that is sending the data:

```
self.indexDelegate = PageViewControllerImage()
```

------ EDIT --------

i am trying to send data from my PageViewController class:

```
var indexDelegate: GetMyIndexDelegate?



func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if (completed && finished) {
        if let currentVC = pageViewController.viewControllers?.last {
            let index = vcArr.index(of: currentVC)

            if index == 3 {

                // call the delegate function in delegate class
                indexDelegate?.getIndex(index: index!)

            }
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // just been trying to define instance first
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let PageViewControllerImageInstance: PageViewControllerImage = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc4") as! PageViewControllerImage
    print("Defined Instance \(PageViewControllerImageInstance)")
    self.indexDelegate = PageViewControllerImageInstance
```

And then receive the data inside class PageViewControllerImage:

```
protocol GetMyIndexDelegate {
    func getIndex(index: Int)
}

import UIKit

class PageViewControllerImage: UIViewController, GetMyIndexDelegate {

//delegate functionto get index
func getIndex(index: Int) {
    if index == 3 {
        print("Inside delegate: \(self)")

    }
}

@IBOutlet var signupImage: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("viewDidLoad: \(self)")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Even with defining the instance of the viewController before setting the delegate its still returning a different instance number:

```
Defined Instance <ParseStarterProject_Swift.PageViewControllerImage: 0x7fb365f06260>

viewDidLoad: <ParseStarterProject_Swift.PageViewControllerImage: 0x7fb365d0c940>

Inside delegate: <ParseStarterProject_Swift.PageViewControllerImage: 0x7fb365f06260>
```

Comment: You are just setting the delegate to a new instance of `PageViewControllerImage`, but you should be setting to an existing instance. Where are you setting the delegate? What is the relationship between `PageViewControllerImage` and the view controller that is acting as the delegate?

Comment: I am setting the reference in viewDidLoad.  PageViewControllerImage is a VC that is part of the PageViewController (index 3)

Comment: `viewDidLoad` of `PageViewControllerImage`? Perhaps you could add to your question a larger vision of what you're trying to accomplish. You're trying to pass data from where to where?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I have edited my question to show more.

Comment: Does your subclass of `UIPageViewController` implement `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`?

Comment: Yes it does: "class pageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {"

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are generally set externally and should be optional.

I am going to assume that the `indexDelegate` is a property on `ViewController`. You should set the delegate when you are transitioning to the `PageViewControllerImage` instance.

This can be achieved in several ways based on how you are transitioning to the `PageViewControllerImage` controller.

If you have a storyboard segue set up, then you can set the delegate in `prepareForSegue`. E.g.:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showPageViewControllerImage" {
        guard let pageViewControllerImage = segue.destination as? PageViewControllerImage
        else {
            return
        }
        self.delegate = pageViewControllerImage
    }
}
```

Or, if you are manually transitioning to the new controller, you can set the delegate to that instance.

Comment: I amended the question to show my attempt at this.  it is still creating a different instance to what is its reference in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

was being instantiated viewControllerAfter within the pagecontroller class

hace to define the delegate to the correct instance of the pageViewController.

self.indexDelegate = self.childViewControllers[2] as! PageViewControllerImage